# biblatex: split bibliography at the begin of a document?

Tags: biblatex, subdividing

I'm trying to print partial bibliographies at the start of a document. One of the things I tried is this:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[defernumbers]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}

\printbibliography[segment=1,sorting=none,resetnumbers]
\printbibliography[segment=2,sorting=none,resetnumbers]

\newrefsegment
\cite{angenendt} \cite{baez/article} \cite{doody}

\newrefsegment
\cite{gillies} \cite{doody} \cite{angenendt} \cite{baez/article}

\end{document}
```

But this gives errors:

```
! Package biblatex Error: Segment '1' not found in section '0'.
```

refsection doesn't work either. Is this a bug or simply not meant to work?

Comment: Reading the docs, I think as it stands it has to be interpreted as a bug (there is no mention of ordering of segments).

Comment: @JosephWright: I made a bug report to get an answer: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/179

Comment: This isn't currently possible since `\newrefsegment` defines the segment and you're using it before it's defined. This would need .aux file support.

Comment: @PLK: Thanks for the confirmation that it isn't meant to work. Could you add it as answer? (I don't think it will be difficult for me to add the aux support in my project: I only need to store \blx@segm@<section>@<segment> and loop over it at the begin of the document to add the entries to some category and use this as filter. biblatex is simply neat. ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't currently possible since `\newrefsegment` defines the segment and you're using it before it's defined. This would need .aux file support.